# Is there a way to concatenate the results of multple mongodb queries together in one statement?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a mongodb database that contains a large amount of data without a highly consistent schema. It is used for doing Google Analytics-style interaction tracking with our applications. I need to gather some output covering a whole month, but I'm struggling with the performance of the query, and I don't really know MongoDB very well at all.

The only way I can get results out is by restricting the timespan I am querying within to one day at a time, using the `_timestamp` field which I believe is indexed by default (I might be wrong).

```
db.myCollection.find({internalId:"XYZ",username:"Demo",_timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2019-09-02T00:00:00.000Z")}}); // Day 1..

db.myCollection.find({internalId:"XYZ",username:"Demo",_timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2019-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2019-09-04T00:00:00.000Z")}}); // Day 2..

db.myCollection.find({internalId:"XYZ",username:"Demo",_timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2019-09-05T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z")}}); // Day 3..
```

This works 'fine', but I'd rather be able to SQL union those seperate queries together - but then I guess I'd still end up timing out.

Ideally I'd end up with each of those queries executing seperately, with the resultset being appended to each time and returned at the end.

I might be better off writing a simple application to do this.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Comment: I presume that you'll do some aggregation on the large data in the application side. If that's the case, maybe you should consider using the mongo's aggregation pipeline instead and let mongo handle all the data on its side, which will also help with the data transferred over the network.

Comment: I should add, I'm just trying to run ad-hoc queries in the shell - I guess my question is whether I should expect any kind of noticable increase in performance, or if the performance of running each query one after the other is representative of what I should expect - to be honest, I'm not expecting a miracle so maybe I just take it like a champ.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, the performance struggle is probably about the size of the data that is being transferred over the network. If you really must have raw data from mongo to your application, all you could try is running your timespan queries in parallel (if you are running the query in console then you will need multiple console) assuming the bandwidth is not satured already.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the conclusion I'm at too. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think I'm going to take a look at writing scripts that executable via the mongo shell.